# How can I use an IntStream to sum specific indexed numbers of an int array?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I've been studying Kotlin and Java with lambdas. I'm trying the use the most of functional programming that I can, even though I don't know much of functional programming.

I'm using HackerRank's problems to study (and Koans to study Kotlin as well). I'm currently solving the problems using both Kotlin and Java 8.

I'm trying to solve the [MiniMax-Sum problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/). Basically, the description is something like this:

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

I'm trying to use the most of the streams API that I can when in Java. The simple question is: how can I reduce, after sorting, the int array to its four first elements (and last, in a different scenario) and sum its values? I was trying to use `IntStream`, but it seems that it's very difficult without using `List`. I was wondering if it possible to use directly the **`int[]` array with `IntStream`** to sort and reduce the elements and them sum it.

Using Kotlin I solved like this:

```
val minSum: Long = arr.sortedArray().copyOfRange(0, 4).sum().toLong()
val maxSum: Long = arr.sortedArray().copyOfRange(1, 5).sum().toLong()
println("$minSum $maxSum")
```

I'm trying to use the `range` method, together with `sorted` and `sum`. It works. The problem is that the sum always returns an `int`, and sometimes the sum is a `long` value. Here's my code:

```
long min = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .sorted()
        .sum();

long max = IntStream.range(1, arr.length + 1)
        .sorted()
        .sum();
```

Result is 10 (min) and 15 (max) for the input `new long[] {256741038, 623958417, 467905213, 714532089, 938071625}`

---

Thanks a lot to everyone that took the time to help! Guess I did not see the `LongStream.of` method :D I solved using 2 different ways (pointed by @Aomine, @nullpointer and @Holger):

```
// using Arrays and Stream
Arrays.sort(arr);
long min = Arrays.stream(arr, 0, 4).sum();
long max = Arrays.stream(arr, 1, 5).sum();

System.out.println(min + " " + max);

// and using LongSummaryStatistics (thanks @Holger)
LongSummaryStatistics ls = LongStream.of(arr).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println((ls.getSum() - ls.getMax()) + " " + (ls.getSum() - ls.getMin()));
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can solve this task by sorting, as shown in other answers, this is unnecessary work. “Summing four out of five” values means “summing all but one”, so all you have to do, is to subtract one element from the sum of all elements. Subtract the maximum element to get the minimum sum of four, subtract the minimum element to get the maximum sum of four:

```
IntSummaryStatistics s = IntStream.of(1, 3, 5, 7, 9).summaryStatistics();
System.out.printf("%d %d%n", s.getSum()-s.getMax(), s.getSum()-s.getMin());
```

```
16 24
```

Or, if the source is an array:

```
IntSummaryStatistics s = Arrays.stream(array).summaryStatistics();
System.out.printf("%d %d%n", s.getSum()-s.getMax(), s.getSum()-s.getMin());
```

Answer (score 4):

You might just be looking for something like [`Intstream.range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int))

> Returns a sequential ordered IntStream from `startInclusive` (inclusive)
>   to `endExclusive` (exclusive) by an incremental step of 1.

Over these then you can perform either `sum` directly or use [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) with `summaryStatistics()` to further access the count, average, max, min etc.

***Edit2***: If you're looking forward to get the sum as `long` use [`summaryStatistics().getSum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#getSum())

***Edit2***: If you're specifically looking to access the statistics of the data of an array, you can use [`Arrays.stream​(int[] array, int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D,int,int)) which would return back an `Instream` as well.

Comment: @Andre Welcome, for the edit over long representation of `sum`, you can use the statistics API and `getSum` further.

Comment: Another question: trying this I see that I don't pass the int[] array to IntStream, just its legth. I guess that this is my main question, since I was already using IntStream hehe. I can say to IntStream that it should have that size, but how do I say to it that it should use those **values**?

Comment: *I can say to IntStream that it should have that size*... if you mean the size of the array, you are anyway doing the same using `range(0, array.length)`

Comment: To stream over a range of an array, you can use `Arrays.stream(array, start, end)`, but as said in my answer, you don't need this anyway.

Comment: I said that using the wrong words I guess. I'm sorry, english is not my first language.I was trying to say that when I use `range(0, array.length)` I'm telling IntStream (or LongStream) to have that size, going starting for 1 and adding 1 to each element. The problem here is that int[] array can have any values. So, how can I tell IntStream that it should use the array that I have in hands?

Comment: @Andre Use `Arrays.stream(array, start, end)` as Holger already pointed out.

Comment: Just for completeness, `IntStream.range(from, to).map(ix -> array[ix])` would work too, but `Arrays.stream(array, from, to)` is canonical.

Answer (score 1):

if you *really* want to use a stream then leverage skip and limit:

```
Arrays.stream(myArray).sorted().limit(4).sum();
Arrays.stream(myArray).sorted().skip(1).limit(4).sum();
```

this assumes you already have an existing array and just want to replicate your Kotlin code in java.

---

As for generating the indices look into [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-).

e.g.

```
IntStream.range(0, 4);
```

returns an `IntStream` from `0` to `3` i.e. `4` is exclusive, [`IntStream.rangeClosed(startInc, endInc)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) enables one to generate indices from `startInc` to `endInc` inclusive.